# Polars - How to add two series that contain lists as elements

Tags: python, python-polars

Trying to add, subtract, two Series that contains datatype List[i64]. The operation seems to be not supported.

```
a = pl.Series("a",[[1,2],[2,3]])
b = pl.Series("b",[[4,5],[6,7]])
c = a+b
```

this gives the error:

```
PanicException: `add` operation not supported for dtype `list[i64]`
```

I would expect a element-wise sum, like would happen with numpy array for example:

```
c = [[5,7],[8,10]]
```

What's the correct syntax to add two series of lists?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Edit: Added expected output, thanks

Comment: I added a feature request on the Polars Github for this: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/9188. It would be nice if the addition worked directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do the following:

```py
c = (a.explode() + b.explode()).reshape((2,-1)).alias('c')

shape: (2,)
Series: 'a' [list[i64]]
[
    [5, 7]
    [8, 10]
]
```

Final thoughts: if your list has a fixed size, then you might consider using the new Polars Array datatype.

Comment: Great solution. Might want to add a `.alias('c')` or similar to change the resulting name, as well

Answer (score 0):

I'd go through a DataFrame like this:

```
(
    pl.DataFrame({'a':a,'b':b})
        .with_row_count('i')
        .explode(['a','b'])
        .groupby('i')
        .agg(c=pl.col('a')+pl.col('b'))
        .get_column('c')
        )
```